# Stocks app added stocks overnight

Tags: ios, icloud

I use the iOS Stocks app to track different securities.  Yesterday I had only four securities listed, yet somehow overnight six additional securities were added. Those additional six securities were tracked in the past, months ago.

How can I tell if the app store past data in the cloud?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it happened again, but this time I know why. I recently did a clean install of macOS Sierra on my computer. macOS Sierra has a Notification Center and a Stocks widget.  This is linked using iCloud to my iPhone's Stocks widget in its Notification Center.